# Laravel Eloquent Pluck produced incorrect data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Trying to get created_at date using pluck.

```
        $campaigns_dates = CampaignHistory::where('status', "Complete")->orderBy( 'created_at', 'ASC' )->pluck('created_at');
        $campaigns_dates = json_decode( $campaigns_dates );
        return $campaigns_dates;
```

//Getting This

```
["2020-06-29T14:19:03.000000Z","2020-06-29T14:19:42.000000Z","2020-07-29T14:23:54.000000Z","2020-08-28T14:55:53.000000Z","2020-08-29T14:17:40.000000Z","2020-09-29T14:18:27.000000Z","2020-09-29T14:21:13.000000Z"]
```

//But Want This

```
Example: ["2020-06-29 14:19:03","2020-06-29 14:19:42"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the map operation to reformat your date as your given format :

```
public function index() {
 
    $campaigns_dates = CampaignHistory::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
        ->pluck('created_at')
        ->map
        ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $campaigns_dates = json_decode($campaigns_dates);
    return $campaigns_dates;
}
```

**Alternative Solution** : There is an alternative solution with `selectRaw()` method, thanks to [@OMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10573560/omr) for provide this solution :

```
public function index() {
 
    $campaigns_dates = CampaignHistory::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
        ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as formatted_date")
        ->pluck('formatted_date');

    $campaigns_dates = json_decode($campaigns_dates);
    return $campaigns_dates;
}
```

Comment: no worries there ... you could have used what you had but they would have had to serialize the model to an array then pull those fields from the array

Comment: side note: with the higher order functions that collection offers you can remove the anonymous function if you wanted to: `$campaigns_dates->map->format(....);`  (just fyi)

Comment: @lagbox thanks you, I really get helped from your comments and answers

Comment: I might also suggest : selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as formatted_date")
            ->pluck('formatted_date')

Comment: if you want to stream line it even further, just return that entire statement (it is a collection, it will get converted to JSON for you)  but now we are just having fun with a small piece of code for the sake of it `:-}`

Comment: @OMR that might be the best solution, you should give an answer :)

Comment: I have upvoted  yours, you can suggest it as a second way

Answer (score 0):

You've got the same date structure as you store in DB.
To change id use `casts` inside `CampaignHistory` model:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
];
```

or you can use function `format` in the loop.

Comment: from the documentation you linked "This format will be used when the **model** is serialized to an array or JSON"

Comment: they would have to serialize their models to an array then pull the fields to be able to use this

Answer (score 0):

you can also use an accessor for that ..For that in your model, you have to just put this

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
     return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') //or what format you need
}
```