# Laravel eloquent: Only retrieve entries where relationship has entries (join)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have a `products` and a `products_marks` table. The `products_marks` table contains a `user_id` and a `product_id` and represents all products which are marked/saved by a user. So, this is more or less something like watch list.

My goal is now to perform an eloquent query which returns me only the products which are also present in the `product_marks` table for a certain `user_id`. For this example let's choose the `user_id` 2.

This is my `products.php` model:

```
public function marks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'products_marks', 'product_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

This is how I achieve what I want at the moment.

I perform an eloquent query with a `join`. But how can I do this with a relationship?

```
$products = Product::join('products_marks', 'products_marks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->where('products_marks.user_id', 2)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: there is a `has` method and a `whereHas` method for what you are looking for

Comment: I haven't deleted this thread here?

Comment: I am talking about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768283/ which was about `$product->end_date` date format

Comment: Anyway, you can do a map operation to get dateTime as you want  `$product = Product::where('id', '1')->get(); $modified = $product->map(function($item, $key) { return [ 'id' => $product->id, 'name' => $product->name, 'end_date' => $product->end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ]; }); dd($modified['end_date']); // 2020-12-09 21:59:59`

Comment: I am very sorry... I deleted it because the question is needless as it is the same time..

Comment: I dont think that it was needless, I already give an same answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64140687/4575350 anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `has` method:

```
$products = Product::has('marks')->where('products_marks.user_id', 2)
                ->orderByDesc('created_at')
                ->paginate(10);
```

Check the doc
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence